# Unwanted table formatting during cut and past in MS Word:Mac 2011

Tags: ms-office

When breaking up a table in order to comment on each section separately, I cut and pasted the sections, which worked well, but then I tried to include introductory paragraphs and these seems to be caught in the table formatting, which doesn't allow me to tab, indent, etc.  How can I get the table formatting turned off for these paragraphs located before and/or after the sections of tables I split up?

Comment: Hi Debbie - need more info, what version of Word you are using for a start?  If you can include more details it will help us help you.

Comment: MS Word for Mac 2011.  This issue only occurred in the sections where I cut and pasted from a table.  It seems to have hung onto the table formatting.  I don't know how to go back and end the table formatting.